# Android screen resolutions

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am following this tutorial [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

There three types of screens

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

But there are three folders

```
drawabale-hdpi
drawabale-mdpi
drawabale-ldpi
```

I placed images of xlarge in hdpi
that of large in mdpi
and that of normal in ldpi
but where to place the images of small screens?
Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 15):

For example, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

and [Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier).

I hope this help.

Answer (score 12):

`hdpi`, `mdpi` and `ldpi` refer to the screen density in dots-per-inch. This is completely separate from the screen size (small, large, etc).

You can have large screen with low density, or a small screen with high density, etc.

You can cater for different screen sizes by putting different layout resources in `res/layout-small`, `res/layout-large`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

These are two different things - hdpi/mdpi/ldpi are screen **densities** (i.e., how many pixels per square centimeter) while xlarge/large/normal/small are screen **sizes** (the physical dimensions of the screen). So the small screen images would go in drawable-small, normal in drawable-normal, etc.

There's a lot more info about this stuff on the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 3):

Screen size has no relation with density. xlarge screen does not mean it has hdpi density. For example tab like galaxy 10.1 pr motorola xoom has xlarge screen but mdpi density so for them you make a separate folder drawable-xlarge. and for this you have to add `android:xlargeScreens="true"` in manifest.

And devices like galaxy s2 or htc desire has hdpi density. Devices with small screens like galaxy pop are mostly have ldpi density, normal screens like galaxy ace are mostly mdpi devices and devices with large screens like galaxy s2 are mostly hdpi devices, and some devices like tab P1000 have large screens but mdpi density and for them you have to make folder drawable-large-mdpi.