# How to support Android Tablet Screen Sizes?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to support different screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

So im making an android app that i want to support both tablet and mobile phone screen sizes i tried using the supports-Screen method but when i type in support xlarge screens gives me an error.
Does anyone know how i could do this?
Thanks

Comment: First try to compile with Android 3.0 and up. And then check the link I've posted below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the src code for the last Google IO application, it support tablets and phone. And has several useful code snippets and design patterns.

[IOsched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Supporting multiple screen sizes in Android can be tricky at first, but http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html will be your best friend.

As a beginner (I'm assuming you are a beginner) you must first create a default layout, then in Android you can begin adjusting your layout for tablets and such. A video that helped me immensely was this video from Google I/O last year. Deffinitely worth your time to watch the whole thing.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq05KqjXTvs&feature=player_embedded