# Guidelines to support multiscreen android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am currently working on an Android app. I am not an UI guy, and just trying out which number fits the best when I make the layout xmls like below:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/my_icon"
    android:layout_height = "30dp"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

I know that `30dp` will work ok on xxhdpi devices because that is what I am using and testing, but I think this will cause trouble when the screen resolution is lower (say, a mhdpi device).

I am wondering if there is any guideline on how to make a layout support different res?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find giudelines in following links

[How to support different screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

Answer (score 0):

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/layout.xml            
res/layout-small/layout.xml      
res/layout-large/layout.xml       
res/layout-xlarge/layout.xml      
res/layout-xlarge-land/layout.xml 

res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png       
res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png       
res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```