# How many AVDs do I need?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

How many AVDs do I need to properly test all layouts? I tried using the stock Google nexus devices but many of the different layouts were tested on the same device. What devices should I use so each layout has an appropriate device? Also, what is the best way to allow flexibility for sp adjustments?

Answer (score 1):

I use:

- an avd for the minimum screen I support ~3.5" (320x240 ldpi or 340x480 mdpi)
- avds for the most common configuration ~4.5" (480x800 hdpi and 720x1280 xhdpi)
- an avd for the maximum configuration ~6" (1920x1080)
- include medium and large tablets in the case I also support tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You need exactly four AVD to support all kinds of devices.

You have to set the different screen size for multiple devices esp. hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi and ldpi.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android).You have to create a separate folder for all devices.

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read [AndroidDevelopers Training](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) and [Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) . You must have at least one AVD for each density type (hdpi,xhdpi etc.). and each with different resolution and physical size.

About the sp- you should define them in dimens.xml file in each values folder(According device width-height).