# Using different size images for phones and tablets

Tags: android

I want to use higher size images for tablets and to decrease the size for phones.
I am doing this for all images in ImageButton.
I have tried placing different size images like hdpi, ldpi, mdpi etc in different folders inside drawable but this is also not working.

I have read that different layouts should be used, but in newer API Levels it is now deprecated.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: But using different folders for layouts is deprecated from 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you Phone/Tablet pixel density , Android system will automatically choose the apt image for your Phone/Tablet. But still, you can explicitly make Android choose different size images. Like this..

// for Phones
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi

//for 7 inch tablets
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

// for 10 inch tablets
drawable-xlarge-mdpi

res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/

Comment: I have done that. I have added all the folders but the size is same in both.

Answer (score 0):

Android will choose which one it will need. So you just have to place images with good sizes on good folders. 
You can check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), you also can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android) post.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the code I found online to reduce the size of the image. Try using this.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroidLoadImageViewActivity extends Activity {

 String imagefile ="/sdcard/IMG_9331.JPG";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile);
        Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(imagefile, 300, 300);
        image.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

 Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height){

     BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);

        int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
        int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
        {
         if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
         {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
         } else {
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
         }
        }

        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
     return bitmap;
    }
}
```