# Screen resolution in Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I writing app for android and have some problem.
I make design and app
But when i installing .apk on phone it have cropped view.
It makes in .xml file or in Manifest?

Or in MainActivity file?

My xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="267.9dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/fone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/privateButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="98.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.7dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/cart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Button
            android:text="Суші"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/sushi"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Роли"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/rolli"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <Button
            android:text="Сети"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/sets"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Холодні Закуски"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/holodni"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#f2565c"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="143.8dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="17.8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13.8dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="143.8dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.6dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="17.8dp"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use different layout folders for different resolution screen. Read below

[How to support different screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

or

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/

Comment: I don't have res folder;
I write in xamarin;
And i want to do many layout for each screen?

Comment: this is not helping http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/

Comment: As i understood, I need 3 more layouts?

Comment: Yes for API level 13 and 13+

Comment: And what i want to select , what device , when design axml?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem related to your design. probably your layout is larger than device i think, use ScrollView as root of your layout then user can scroll in it to display all view .

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Create folder inside res:

**res/layout/my_layout.xml       // layout for normal screen size ("default")**

**res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size**

**res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra-large screen size**

**res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml     // layout for extra-large landscape screen size**