# Support for different screens in android

Tags: java, android

I tried almost everything. But I have many queries which need support for multiple screens in Android. For different screen resolutions, I read here in this article http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html. I tried that but how can I handle this if I have 50 different activities? And which code should I write in my java files?

I even searched on developer.android link, but same result. I'm really confused. How can I make my app compatible with all devices. I tried to make a different layout file for all resolutions but when it comes to the listview part having an Adapter class where we gave a layout link, it requires too much time to fix every java file. Can anyone suggest a solution for this? How do I manage this and what code I should write in my java files so it will check automatically?

Comment: I thinks that the task you wnat to achieve is very difficult task, there are thousands of different mobile (isn't like apple :p), but you can concentrate using the dp size in elements of the ui and the dimens xml files for different resolutions, this files must go in the values-"resolution" folder, for example: values-small. look this, it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Comment: @user1977204 Thanks but I saw this question but I can't get it how can I use this. Still I again try. Thank u..

Comment: Ok, i added a short answer fot you can take the general idea of it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to support different screen size in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)