# The proper way of sorting layout and drawable for different sizes and screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have scrolled through loads of documents and questions trying to figure out the right way of giving proper UI experience. I have a app with complex designs . I need to know how to scale my design to look fine in all devices. I got solutions mentioning that a normal layout folder with all layout , and i have traced all textview sizes and image view sizes to **values, values-sw 480dp, values-sw 720 dp** . Is this the proper dimens? My problem is that though the textsizes and image sizes scale up , still UI doesnt seem right. I mean the margin and all. What is the right solution out? any help?

Comment: also do that for dimensions too in dimens.xml

Comment: you mean the layout margin and padding and all?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: Can you tell me if values, values-480dp and 720dp are done enough to cover all screen sizes? Also instead of mentioning the padding/ margin in dimen folder , could i instead make layout- 480 and 720 folder and paste the whole layout from normal size design and do the minor changes(like done in layout-land) ?

Comment: Make all sizes proportional to screen dimensions so it will look exactly the same in all devices.

Comment: yes you can do that also if you don't want to define dimens.xml

Comment: @Nanoc : How exactly to do that?

Comment: @DAgrawal using DisplayMetrics to get the screen size, then always use a fraction of that number for all your view sizes. use (screenWidth*0.05) for margin for example.

Comment: @Nanoc This has to be done programattically, which doesnt seem a easier option right now, as it then has to be done for all margins and so, which is going to be lengthy. Instead changes i xml would be better.

Comment: Maybe you should never have started with xml

Answer (score 0):

@D try out to make different folder for different screen sizes like layout-hdpi

you can find the best practice for layout handling [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android) 
and see the Google documentation [hear](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Drawable qualifiers also

drawable

drawable-sw320dp

drawable-sw480dp

drawable-sw600dp

drawable-sw720dp