# Android adjusting icons when on tablet it becomes larger

Tags: android, android-layout, icons

I have been developing my android app and only trying it on a nexus 5 (1080 x 1920) virtual device (genymotion) and I have all the layouts and fonts to my liking, but when I tried it on a sony xperia tablet (1280 x 800), some of the icons became to large.

Here's what it looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOtQ2.png

I'm not sure if I should be creating another type of layout just for a change of resolution. Or can i do it dynamically?

Comment: Put different images for each screen sizes.

Comment: but they're icons that i got using "Vector Asset", and I picked a local svg file, which I assumed will re adjust automatically?

Comment: Should be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android