# Supporting different screen sizes and densities in regards to layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how to make my app support different screen sizes and densities, including tablets, regarding the layout. I've found different answers on SO, but I can't find one that explains this issue the best.

I've already included this in my Manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android) answer, I should create multiple layout folders such as small, large, xlarge.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) I should create multiple layouts and use size qualifiers such as `sw<N>dp`.

Which would be the best solution if my app needs to support both phones and tablts?

**Additional question:**
In connection with the abovementioned question, I have a recycler view with list of items. If the screen is portrait then there's a list, if the screen is landscape, then there's grid.

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mBinder.rvHistoryList.setLayoutManager(manager);
    } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        mBinder.rvHistoryList.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }
```

But, if the app is used on a tablet in portrait mode I would like the items to be in a grid ordered by 2 in a row, if the app is used on a tablet in landscape mode I would like the items to be in a grid ordered by 4 in a row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is a difference between *should* and *can*. Do you really need any more than 1 main layout? If you want to support both tablets and phones, then maybe 3-4 layouts? 2x portrait and 2x landscape? You don't need to target screen density unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Well, yes, I need to support both phones and tablets. How would I achieve this by your proposal of having 2x portrait and 2x landscape layouts?

Comment: res/layout is portrait and res/layout-land is landscape. if you need more  then a `sw<N>dp` folder

Answer (score 0):

Creating few layouts for different size is old and confusing method.
You can set weight for each layout and component.

This is good tutorial for beginning.

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html