# How to create a compatible layout for every screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to create an app...But when I use to test my app on various devices the app is not appear in full screen/same resolution as the device having...

Comment: Share your layout here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support different screen size in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android)

Comment: You can read more about designing layouts for different screen sizes here https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I tried this wrap_content and match_content concept but not able to add four button 2horizontal and 2vertical....And also if I define button size then it will not work for every device!

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma Not able to upload images...

Comment: @VinitMaheshwari share your source at first, then share the image through imgur

Answer (score 0):

you may use `ConstaintLayout` to make a responsive UI, you can follow below official docs
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

An other option is `PercentRelativeLayout` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

For a 3*3 matrix, you can use `Tablelayout` something like this

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="first" />
            <TextView
                android:text="second"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="third"
                android:gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="first" />
            <TextView
                android:text="second"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="third"
                android:gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="first" />
            <TextView
                android:text="second"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:text="third"
                android:gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

or you may use combination of `linearlayouts` with `weightSum` and `layout_weight`

Comment: Can u send me a main activity layout xml which have 3*3 matrix type buttons?

Comment: better to search and explore things yourself, if you still couldn't find make things better, share your code and ask to improve. happy coding :)

Comment: see my edits. hope it will help you to get the idea.

Comment: I'm adding Button(9 buttons) in a 3*3 matrix form..With some widht and height but when I try to run app in different devices of different screen size I saw the buttons are not adjusting to screen size they got out of the screen or shrinks

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraint Layout as suggested by Junaid otherwise use weightsum properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for `dp` you not need to make different layout for each resolution https://github.com/intuit/sdp

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
}
```

> Example

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/give_us_a_review_landmine_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_27sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_43sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_50sdp" />
```

Comment: how did you check can you please explain or put code?

Comment: First I went to gradle than wrote the code than clicked on button syn now it shows error

Comment: error? what error appear?, please check updated answer or link contain sample inside git repo.

Comment: Sir my main problem is I'm adding 9 buttons with some size and background but when I run the app in different devices the buttons goes out of the screen or shrinks...I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding Button(9 buttons) in a 3*3 matrix form..With some widht and height but when I try to run app in different devices of different screen size I saw the buttons are not adjusting to screen size they got out of the screen or shrinks