# In small screen size phones the layout gets extra-zoomed without making extra folders

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, screen

Screen size = 5"3 inch

[image]

Screen size = 4"3 inch

[image]

Here you can clearly see the difference, in small screen size phones the last option is not even getting displayed. Please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you setup different screen sizes for xlarge, large, normal and small?

Comment: See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android

Comment: No i didn't setup anything like that . should i do that ?

Comment: You can use dimens or layout weight to create responsive layout design.

Comment: Yes you should, see the question I have linked. Basically you will make 4 four folder, one for each size. then make a xml layout for each and have any images in drawable folders that relate to the sizes

Comment: Is there a way by which i can establish the same ratio in all screen size phones . Like in 5inch phones it will get displayed a bit bigger and in 4 inch phones it will be displayed smaller but respective layout elements will be of same ratio.

Comment: @saurabhgupta Yes, you can do it by setting layout weight. If you add your xml code, I may help you.

Comment: Post your xml, It will help get the answer you need

Comment: @tahsinRupam Bro . i just found the desired solution, I will now try using sdp instead of dp , anyways thanks for the support.

Comment: @Phil3992 Thanks phil for attaching the link.

Comment: @saurabhgupta Yeah, dp will give you better result. But for text-size prefer using sp.