# Android support for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-button, android-relativelayout, screen-size, android-layoutparams

I have created this layout. in which showing textview and below it , it has share buttons for insta, fb, copy,tweet.

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Sub_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/linerlayout_background"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


      android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/txt_hash"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_hash"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button">


            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fb"
                android:id="@+id/fb"/>


            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/insta"
                android:id="@+id/insta"/>


            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tweet"
                android:id="@+id/tweet"/>


            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/doc"
                android:id="@+id/doc"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have `recyclerview` which has this content to view. Now I want to fit these buttons properly according to every device screen size. I have no idea about `layoutparams`, I have referred links but I need to understand how to calculate size of a particular button inside(Framelayout/RelativeLayout/LinearLayout/Buttons(4)).

Comment: Please read this **[Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)**

Comment: it is very time consuming i have refered this documents can u provide solution to this or any example, because i cannot able to get proper understanding through this documentory links @Nilesh

Comment: you need to use `ConstraintLayout` for this also check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/8255985/7666442

Comment: can i do that without using constraintLayout? using LayoutParams ?

Comment: have u check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8256573/7666442

Comment: constraint layout is a pain in the mouse but it gets the job done. just make sure you dock correct handles to correct surfaces or handles.

Comment: Use [sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for dimension (almost works).

Comment: Have you considered layout_weight? It automatically resizes elements to the screen, by making proportionally sizing items in relation to other elements.

Comment: i got my answer , u can check i have posted on my question .. anyways ,Thank u all . @NileshRathod Fractal AbhayKoradiya S.Czop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who want to set screen without using constraintview or creating different .xmls and image files can follow this method as i got the solution.

i have implemented in my adapter.class

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; 
    int deviceHeight= displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    int Linearwidth=    (deviceWidth*692 ) /720;
    int Linearheight =   (deviceHeight *100 ) /1280;

    int iv_width = (deviceWidth *78)/720;
    int iv_height=(deviceHeight*78)/1280;

    int Text_Linear_Width = (deviceWidth * 710)/720;
    int Text_Linear_Height =(deviceHeight * 319)/1280;
    txt_hash.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Text_Linear_Width * 28 / 720);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(iv_width,iv_height);

    lp.leftMargin = (Linearwidth*78)/720;
    lp.rightMargin = (Linearheight*78)/1280;
    lp.bottomMargin=(Linearheight*200)/1280;
    lp.topMargin=(Linearheight*200)/1280;


    fb.setLayoutParams(lp);
    insta.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tweet.setLayoutParams(lp);
    doc.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, it can support any device depend on it' s weight attribute.
the question is you have no idea about layout params. for the problem.you can links to [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams).

For the recyclerView you mentioned, you can get the button's layout params in the onCreateViewHolder.

```
 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.story_item, parent,
            false);
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
    //for example:one quater of the device's width
    layoutParams.width="your width";
    layoutParams.height="your height";
    //and so on,the layoutParams also has extra parameter
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    ...
    }
```

Comment: u can check out my answer @alei long