# Supporting Different Screen Sizes With modern techniques as of 2019

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

This question has been asked more then 100 times on SO, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android) question was asked 8 years before. And for sure the methods define in discussion are obsolete.

With the new designing components such as Constraint Layout and changes in bucket such as MipMap and other changes in techniques I want to discuss now the modern techniques.

What are the best practices for making an app to support large number of devices when it comes to designing specifically. I have more then 3 years of experience in android and still I am keen to learn the new things which are not generally discussed anywhere officially. So can you tell me what rules must be followed to support different screen sizes?

> **For Example I am going to show you screen which we must look on all devices to look like same**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        />


    <!-- Email Label -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



    <!-- Password Label -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilLoginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/btnLogin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This looks perfectly good on mobile devices, but looks worst on tablets and large screen.

see the picture below on mobile screen.

[image]

see the picture below on tablets

[image]

> **Question: What what should be done to show centered beautiful layout in tablet too instead of wide full screen edit text. In other words
>   what should be followed to show layout same on all devices according
>   to new techniques?**
>
> Note: I know if we apply some properties we can limit width of
>   edittext in given example but we can not use such properties in other
>   complex layouts.

Comment: With 3 years of experience in Android, your should know that you should define different xml for different resolution sets instead of using only 1 layout for all devices

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen yes, but that process is also deprecated, I am not confirmed but I read it somewhere

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen you still doing that when developing app in android?

Comment: I only develop applications for phone, but from the point of view of a designer, large devices should has a specific layout to take advantages of large screen (display more content,...)

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen for phone you still have to manage for different screen sizes? What strategy do you follow?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try below library which manages all the screen size resolution automatically. I am using this in my current projects.

**For Dimension**

`implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'`

**For TextSize**

`implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'`

For More Info https://github.com/intuit/sdp