# Alternative to SDP in Android to create Layout for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

[Here is a single layout built using sdp:

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbY0p.png)
https://github.com/intuit/sdp
Here is a single layout built using sdp:

How to create Layout like Sdp without using SDP Api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255985/how-to-support-different-screen-size-in-android . Check this out. Using sdp and ssp is alright for your own projects but for larger projects using constraint layout and match constraints effectively should do the trick.

Comment: And what about Text sizes ?? Will they Adapt sizes to displays??

Comment: Yes it would. dp works moderately well for text sizes etc. It's just images that have difficulty in rendering