# Which android layout and drawable resources should galaxy tab support for development?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I am Developing Application with multiple device support.
Now i want to know which Layout is Galaxy Tab Support? I mean like layout-large or layout-small, layout-xlarge or anyother ??
Samw with which drawable is supported by galary tab for images to place. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the new size qualifiers in the supports-screens.(for android 3.2 and above)

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).

480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Refer to the [dev guide on screen supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: devices like Galaxy nexus already posses 720p (1280x720) on phones. Its better to go with Uttam's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Now I want to know which Layout is Galaxy Tab Support?

The answer for this particular question is  dependant on the inch of the device whether it is a 10 inch or 7 inch or whatever.You can have a look at this image provided by the developer.android.com.which clearly describes the layout for the respective inches of the devices.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you set your target sdk level to anything less than 9, then support for extra-large screens is assumed to be false. If you set targetSdkVersion=9 in the manifest, then xlarge support is assumed to be true.and check out my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665194/840861) answer.

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Best of luck