# how to add address layout-small activity.xml in class

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size, setcontentview

Hi i with this tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/q/7665194/840861 make res/layout-small/my_layout.xml and i want to add this xml file in main activity but can not to address it like this tutorial https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

i want like this code :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_tablet);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
}
```

my code is :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

but can not this address xml:

```
setContentView(R.layout-small.activity_main);
```

and i create success folder layout-small and past xml file activity_main but can not add address

im sorry im  not good in english language

Answer (score 0):

> make res/layout-small/my_layout.xml

There is no reason to create a `res/layout-small/` directory. That has the same effect as `res/layout/`, saying to use these resources for every screen size.

The size qualifiers (`-small`, `-normal`, `-large`, `-xlarge`, and their more modern equivalents like `-w640dp`) say "use these resources for anything that is this size *or larger*". So, `res/layout-large/` resources would not be used on `-small` or `-normal` screens, and `res/layout-w640dp/` resources would not be used on devices whose current width is less than 640dp. But all screens are `-small` or larger, so `res/layout-small/` will match every device.

---

```
setContentView(R.layout-small.activity_main);
```

When you *use* a resource, you never put the qualifiers in. Replace that with:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```